# I have a cube that spins all over the place when I hit an object.(the camera and character spins) UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple movement that relvolves around moving foward depending on where I look. The camera is made to follow the player. The problem I am havaing is that whenever I hit an object, my character(along with the camera) start spinning crazily all over the place. (I am new to coding)

Here is the code to the movement of where my character is facing :

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    public float movementSpeed = 10;
    public float turningSpeed = 60;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }

    void Update() {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turningSpeed * 
Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Rotate(0, horizontal,0);

    float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")* turningSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.Rotate(vertical, 0, 0);

    float movement = Input.GetAxis("Foward") * movementSpeed * 
    Time.deltaTime;
    transform.Translate(0, 0,movement);

   }
}
```

(Sorry for bad format)
The Mouse X just makes it so that it rotates on the x axis of mouse(same with y axis). The Foward is just the vertical input preset in unity.
Here is the code to the lookAt player :

```
public class LookAtCamera : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject target;

    void LateUpdate() {
        transform.LookAt(target.transform);
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `Input.GetAxis("Foward")` return? I'm guessing it is supposed to be Forward instead of Foward?

Comment: Yes, I have it named wrong under the input and coding. It works as expected though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

**I believe your rigidbody is being more heavily affected than what you desire by the bounce force occuring as you hit the object.**

---

Possible solutions

Depending on which collider type acts as your legs, the weight of the objects involved, what behaviour you intend and more the solution can vary.

**Possible solution 1:**

One option is to freeze the rotation of your object on it's Rigidbody component, you can decide which axes to freeze rotation on. If freezed they can't be pushed by outside forces.

**Possible solution 2:**

If you wish the player to only be affected by your script you can set the rigidbody kinematic, meaning that it only is affected by scripts and animation. This is a contrast to being set to dynamic where other objects can affect it.

**Possible solution 3:**

Play around with the angular drag and mass of the rigidbody to slow down rotation.